# Improving performance when using RxJava flowable to handle Android Room queries

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, android-room

My app is collecting sensor values from the accelerometer with the highest possible sample rate (~200 Hz on my device) and saves the values inside a Room database. I also want to frequently update some graphs with the latest measurements, lets say a refresh rate of 5 times per second. Ever since the app also collects the linear acceleration (without g) also with ~200 Hz (so two sensors each with roughly 200Hz inserting values into the database) I noticed a strong decrease in the apps performance and I have a lag of a few seconds between collected acceleration values and them showing up in the plot.
From the profiler my guess is that the RxComputationThread is the bottleneck since it is active almost all the time due to the Flowables.

I use sample() to limit the receiver updates since my graphs do not need to update super often. This led to an acceptable performance, when I just collected one sensor. I saw that RxJava provides an interval() method to limit the emit frequency from an emitter side, but that does not seem to available to me ? (Unresolved reference).

Maybe someone has an idea how to improve the performance? I like the concepts of RxJava and Room in general and would like to stick with them, but I am pretty much stuck at this point.

Here is the code I use to observe the Room SQL table and update the graphs:

```
// Observe changes to the datasource and create a new subscription if necessary
sharedViewModel.dataSource.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { source ->
    Log.d("TAG", "Change observed!")
    when (source) {
        "acc" -> {
            val disposableDataSource =
                sharedViewModel.lastSecondsAccelerations
                    .sample(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .onBackpressureDrop()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe { lastMeasurements ->
                        Log.d("TAG", Thread.currentThread().name)
                        if (sharedViewModel.isReset.value == true && lastMeasurements.isNotEmpty()) {
                            val t =
                                lastMeasurements.map { (it.time.toDouble() * 1e-9) - (lastMeasurements.last().time.toDouble() * 1e-9) }
                            val accX = lastMeasurements.map { it.accX.toDouble() }
                            val accY = lastMeasurements.map { it.accY.toDouble() }
                            val accZ = lastMeasurements.map { it.accZ.toDouble() }

                            // Update plots
                            updatePlots(t, accX, accY, accZ)
                        }
                    }
            compositeDisposable.clear()
            compositeDisposable.add(disposableDataSource)
        }
        "lin_acc" -> {
            val disposableDataSource =
                sharedViewModel.lastSecondsLinAccelerations
                    .sample(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .onBackpressureDrop()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe { lastMeasurements ->
                        Log.d("TAG", Thread.currentThread().name)
                        if (sharedViewModel.isReset.value == true && lastMeasurements.isNotEmpty()) {
                            val t =
                                lastMeasurements.map { (it.time.toDouble() * 1e-9) - (lastMeasurements.last().time.toDouble() * 1e-9) }
                            val accX = lastMeasurements.map { it.accX.toDouble() }
                            val accY = lastMeasurements.map { it.accY.toDouble() }
                            val accZ = lastMeasurements.map { it.accZ.toDouble() }

                            // Update plots
                            updatePlots(t, accX, accY, accZ)
                        }
                    }
            compositeDisposable.clear()
            compositeDisposable.add(disposableDataSource)
        }
    }
})
```

The query for getting the last 10 seconds of measurements

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM acc_measurements_table WHERE time > ((SELECT MAX(time) from acc_measurements_table)- 1e10)")
fun getLastAccelerations(): Flowable<List<AccMeasurement>>
```

Comment: Just a thought, could the mapping be a source of problems (for large enough lists)? Perhaps it's happening on the main thread because the logic is in subscribe { ... }. RxJava has a map operator

Comment: Another thought, perhaps Room is the bottleneck. That's a lot of inserts and querying. Is it possible for you to pinpoint the problem?

Comment: I've been looking into Room v Traiditonal SQLite in regards to performance and there appears to be at least a 20% overhead when using Room. e.g. Traditional `Run ALL From 2019-11-07 22:16:31 To 2019-11-07 22:19:28 Elapsed = 5882` and for the same 10 runs using Room `Run ALL From 2019-11-07 22:17:12 To 2019-11-07 22:18:23 Elapsed = 7449` (Elapsed is perhaps the wrong term it's an accumlation of the times taken for the DB access).

Comment: But still, 20% slower probay does not mean going from smooth to choppy. 1) what happens if you remove the code from subscribe { ... } (ie leave it empty) 2) checkout backpressure strategies, perhaps something interesting there

Comment: I'm sorry, but I need some more information to answer you. Why are you reading the data from a Room database? Don't you have direct access to the sensor?
Can't you read from sensor directly? I don't think that it is a good idea to channel all those data through Room for the porpoise of showing them.

Also, do you need to save them into a local DB or that was just the way you did it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments, I figured out now, what the bottleneck was. The issue was the huge amount of insertion calls, not too surprising. But it is possible to improve the performance by using some kind of buffer to insert multiple rows at a time.

This is what I added, in case someone runs in the same situation:

```
class InsertHelper(private val repository: Repository){
    var compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    private val measurementListAcc: FlowableList<AccMeasurement> = FlowableList()
    private val measurementListLinAcc: FlowableList<LinAccMeasurement> = FlowableList()

    fun insertAcc(measurement: AccMeasurement) {
        measurementListAcc.add(measurement)
    }
    fun insertLinAcc(measurement: LinAccMeasurement) {
        measurementListLinAcc.add(measurement)
    }

    init {
        val disposableAcc = measurementListAcc.subject
            .buffer(50)
            .subscribe {measurements ->
                GlobalScope.launch {
                    repository.insertAcc(measurements)
                }
                measurementListAcc.remove(measurements as ArrayList<AccMeasurement>)
            }

        val disposableLinAcc = measurementListLinAcc.subject
            .buffer(50)
            .subscribe {measurements ->
                GlobalScope.launch {
                    repository.insertLinAcc(measurements)
                }
                measurementListLinAcc.remove(measurements as ArrayList<LinAccMeasurement>)
            }

        compositeDisposable.add(disposableAcc)
        compositeDisposable.add(disposableLinAcc)
    }
}
```

```
// Dynamic list that can be subscribed on
class FlowableList<T> {
    private val list: MutableList<T> = ArrayList()
    val subject = PublishSubject.create<T>()

    fun add(value: T) {
        list.add(value)
        subject.onNext(value)
    }

    fun remove(value: ArrayList<T>) {
        list.removeAll(value)
    }
}
```

I basically use a dynamic list to buffer a few dozens measurement samples, then insert them as whole in the Room Database and remove them from the dynamic list. Here is also some information why batch insertion is faster: https://hackernoon.com/squeezing-performance-from-sqlite-insertions-with-room-d769512f8330

Im still quite new to Android Development, so if you see some mistakes or have suggestions, I appreciate every comment :)